# How to access the holder element outside view Holder in adapter android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a ViewHolder Class.

```
class VHHeader extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView txtTitle;
        RecyclerView recyclerView;

        public VHHeader(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtHeader);
            this.recyclerView =(RecyclerView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);


        }
    }
```

Now I want to access this View Holders recycler view in some different method in same adapter class .

```
Public void useRecyclerView(){
}
```

How to use the element of View Holder in this method.

Comment: I do not understand what your aim is here. What/where are you using `useRecyclerView()`?

Comment: Instead of this, change your object variable and call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(changedItemPosition);`

Comment: i specifically need access to the elements of holder as i need to do some operation on them before calling notify.

Comment: Do you need to set a specific position of your recyclerview items?

Comment: Specifically, you need that viewholder on recyclerview item click?

Comment: yes i need instance of that view holder

Comment: I do not know intention but you are creating holder in onCreateViewHolder, so you can store it as private variable. I think it will be no use of you. Please share what you want to achieve by accessing view.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want to use your view holder elements in some of the methods with in same adapter. so for that you need to pass the view holder and position in the function in which you can use your view holder elements.

Example.

```
@Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(final AdapterName.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

                holder.elementname.setText(arrayList.get(position).getYourMethodName());


                holder.elementname.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                yourMethodName(holder,position);

                }
            });
        }



    //and in that method    you can use your view holder elements.

    private void yourMethodName(final AdapterName.ViewHolder holder,final int position)
    {
         holder.elementname.setText(arrayList.get(position).getYourMethodName());
    }       


//This way you can use your elements
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand, you want to make some changes on item click of recyclerview. You don't need to store your viewholder. You can set clicklistener on adapter's onBindViewHolder method like:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VHHeader holder, final int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do your operations here like
            holder.txtTitle.setText("new title");
        }
    });
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** If you want to use the holder elements inside you adapter class then you can create holder object:

```
@Override
public AdapterClass.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    adaptercontext = parent.getContext(); //to get the activity context use this line.
    MyViewHolder dataObjectHolder = new MyViewHolder(view); //in this way you can use the holder object.

}
```

**2.** If you want to access outside then use this MyViewHolder as a argument of the method, like this:

```
private void update_data(MyViewHolder holder)
{
holder.edittext1.setText("Updated value");
//for getting updated holder you can use **holder.getAdapterPosition()** to get the position of the element.
}
```

Thankyou. If any modifications you feel please let me know and corrections too.
Enjoy Coding.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Still helps in 2023. Thanks for the snippets.

Comment: glad to know it helps. Happy coding :). @priyamtheone

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        ImageView icons;
        CheckBox checkBox;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final CategoryChildModel current = data.getItems().get(position);

        holder.title.setText(current.getName());
}
```